# Exporting binary file from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, elevation, rgb, binary

For a hobby flight simulator C++ project, satellite RGB and elevation data is needed. Since a few days I am trying Google Earth Engine. It is amazing at showing the data as a map. I see GeoTIFF export options, but I don't know how to load/convert that data into C++.

Is there a possibility to export a binary file?

For example where each pixel is represented by 5 bytes: RGBEE. (EE being a 16-bit int representing the elevation in meters.)

So the binary file would be of this format RGBEERGBEERGBEE...RGBEE with a total length of 5 times the number of pixels. Example: map of 100 by 100 pixels > file size= 50000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You could export a GeoTiff from  a suitable Digital Elevation Model [(DEM)](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/tags/elevation) and from your satellite image.

Then you could extract lat/long and elevation from your DEM like here:
[Export the elevation values and its corresponding lat and long as a csv file in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/451611/148446)

Then find the coordinates of your pixels in your GeoTiff satellite image with the rgb data (take care they have the same coordinate reference system)
[How to find coordinates of pixels of a GeoTIFF image with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/394455/148446)

[How to export a RGB image from Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/370524/148446)

Last step is the combination of both data sets. Use the coordinates to connect colour and elevation.

But in your binary format you only keep the elevation, your position (lat/long) info has gone.